# Passing a param to new controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4.21
Ruby 2.5
```

I have an Organization model, with the standard MVC structure.

The show action, displays a view of the organization (name, contact info, etc).

I added an OrganizationNote MVC structure.

What I would like to do, is in the Organization show view, add a "Add Note" button, something like:

```
link_to 'Add Note', new_organization_note_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

But I need to pass the organization id, to the New OrganizationNote. Right now, no parameters are passed with the call, when I tried:

```
link_to 'Add Note', new_organization_note_path(@organization.id), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

I did not see any parameters passed.

How can I accomplish this, and do I need to create any special routes?

## Edits:

I added the following to routes.rb:

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :organization_notes
end
```

Which produced the following routes:

```
organization_organization_notes GET /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes(.:format) organization_notes#index
POST /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes(.:format) organization_notes#create
new_organization_organization_note GET /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/new(.:format) organization_notes#new
edit_organization_organization_note GET /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/:id/edit(.:format) organization_notes#edit
organization_organization_note GET /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/:id(.:format) organization_notes#show
PATCH /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/:id(.:format) organization_notes#update
PUT /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/:id(.:format) organization_notes#update
DELETE /organizations/:organization_id/organization_notes/:id(.:format) organization_notes#destroy
```

And I modified the link to:

```
link_to 'Add Note', new_organization_organization_note_path(:organization_id => @organization.id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
```

and in the organization_notes_controller.rb, I have:

```
def new
  @organization_note = OrganizationNote.new
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
end
```

When I click on the Add Note, button, I get the following message:

```
Incomplete response received from application
```

And from the log file:

```
Started GET "/organizations/176/organization_notes/new" for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2018-04-02 03:24:32 +0000
Processing by OrganizationNotesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"organization_id"=>"176"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOrganization Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` WHERE `organizations`.`id` = 176 LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered organization_notes/_form.html.erb (34.7ms)
  Rendered organization_notes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (35.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I did not see any parameters passed"? If you use Inspect Element in your browser, what does the `href` parameter of your `a` tag contain?

Comment: I mean in the log file, I did not see any params

Comment: What does `new_organization_note_path` look like in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: resources :organization_notes, nothing special for that specific route. rake routes, produces: new_organization_note GET /organization_notes/new(.:format) organization_notes#new

Answer (score 1):

To make `OrganizationNote`s use URLS relative to `Organization`s, you'll need to use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). This will allow you to specify an argument for which Organization you want the Note to apply to, e.g.

```
resources :organizations do
    resources :organization_notes
end
```

You can use `rails routes` to confirm that the path now includes a parameter.

(If you only want this relative route for creating Notes, you can also just use a single custom route instead of the `resources` function).

Comment: Please see edits. The param is getting passed, but I am getting a 500 response

Comment: What is your OrganizationNotesController#new view file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution.

```
# routes.rb
resources :organizations do
  resources :organization_notes
end

# new method
def new
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  @organization_note = @organization.organization_notes.build
end

# views
link_to 'Add Note', new_organization_organization_note_path(:organization_id => @organization.id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
```